# Can you use data that you got from a query in another query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I've got some data from a SELECT query. Can I use this as a table later, meaning naming it something then using its rows and columns in other queries?

I can't solve this problem for the life of me. I'm a beginner. It's just one table but I just can't get a query working. Here is what I have:

Hotel table and Room table (I'll just need to use the Room table; I mentioned Hotel just as a reference point for understanding).

Room has the following columns: (Number,HID) - this is a composite primary key; Number is the numerical number of the room and HID is the ID of the hotel which it belongs to. I also have one more column, Name. Now the problem is:

**Find all the Hotels which only have rooms Named OneBedroom**

I tried (and failed) by doing it by selecting all HIDs from Room, then filtering on not exist(hotels that have at least one non-OneBedroom named room), but I couldn't make this work.

```
Room

Number    HID    Name

1         H1     OneBedroom
2         H2     OneBedroom
3         H1     OneBedroom
4         H1     OneBedroom
5         H2     TwoBedroom
6         H3     OneBedroom

Desired Output:    HID
           H1
           H3
```

Comment: show us some sample data and desire output.

Comment: Is that, hotels where all of the rooms are named `OneBedroom`, or hotels which have at least one room named `OneBedroom`?

Comment: That is called a sub query! Need some field names from your tables.

Comment: @CollinD I dont want go to an hotel where all rooms are called OneBedroom

Comment: Hotels where all rooms are named ONeBedroom

Comment: Im giving an example soon

Comment: Hotels with exactly one bedroom called OneBedroom

Comment: I gave an example, pay attention everyone. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using `group by` plus `having` with a conditional `count`, so no need to include aditional subquery.

This return hotel with all `room =  "OneBedroom"`, remember `COUNT` only count `values <> NNLL`

```
 SELECT `hid` 
 FROM `room`
 GROUP BY `hid`
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN `name` != "OneBedroom" THEN 1 END ) = 0
```

At least one bedroom is call "OneBedroom"`

```
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN `name`  = "OneBedroom" THEN 1 END ) >= 1
```

The default value for `CASE` is `NULL` so no need for `ELSE` part

Answer (score 2):

I suspect something like this would do it

```
SELECT DISTINCT `hid` FROM `room` WHERE
    `room`.`hid` NOT IN
        (SELECT `hid` as `hid` FROM `room` WHERE `name` != "OneBedroom");
```

Untested, might be crap, but seems like it should work. Basically, the inner query gets all `hid`'s of rooms that are not `OneBedroom`s. We then subtract all of those `hid`'s from a full list of `hid`'s.

Comment: DAm! Skillz bro! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I'm going with a table like this from what you describe:

```
table Room
HID    Number        Name
----------------------------------------
 1      101          OneBedroom
 1      102          OneBedroom
 1      103          TwoBedroom
 1      201          Suite
 2      101          OneBedroom
 2      102          OneBedroom
 2      103          OneBedroom
```

which I assume connects to a table Hotel:

```
table Hotel
HID    name
------------------
 1     StayOver
 2     SleepTite
```

Now for the query:

```
SELECT h.name 
FROM Hotel h
WHERE h.HID NOT IN (SELECT r.HID 
FROM Room r
WHERE name != 'OneBedroom');
```

which will give you a list of the hotel names with only one bedroom rooms.

Works on SQLite with sample data. Should be okay.

EDIT - based on edited question:

```
SELECT h.HID . . .
```

instead of h.name in above query.